# It would be bad idea to implement File Server with Web Service?

Tags: cloud

**Task:**
Implement an Web Service and an Android Application that use the WS. A cloud Application.

So, i am thinking for File Server. It would be bad idea to use WS instead of ftp? i know that ws are not recommended for large files.

-- Your opinions...

Answer (score 0):

If you need your mobile App to get real time data, DB data or some cpu heavily processed data you need regular web service, for example RestFull API.

But if you need your mobile App to get from the web files - Use ftp.

I don't see any reason mixing... So yes - If you need RestFull API don't use ftp bypass or something like this.

Comment: Actually it is a project for university. I choose to create something that contains cloud computing, web services and android. I am rly so pissed off. I can't find any idea to create a cloud app that uses WSs. PS: I don't wanna create small sh1ts like "cloud notes"... looking for something harder. I was thinking for file server with WS but i think it would be fail. WS are not to transfer large files. So, maby i create something like "Cloud Gallery or Cloud Images".

Comment: What is your SW requirement?

Comment: Nothing was defined.The main idea was an overview of these tecnologies and then implementing one application with these technologies. The idea was just to implement: 1) Web service 2) Android App that use the WS.... then i decided for an Cloud App, so (a ws in the cloud and android that call ws functions).

Comment: @GeorgeJ ftp not relevant here

Comment: Sorry for opening discus here but im new and i can't find link for PMing you. So, i was wondering... how the applications like Dropbox are made? they are using web services to transfer files?

Comment: 1. In so ain't pm. 2. Probably they have the whole package: server side with restfull api as web service, sql db and storage for files (like 'ftp'). Start with Amazon web services they offer free tier of all this

Comment: 1st, ty for participating in this discus. I really appreciate your answers. Well. I know the AWS (EC2, IIS), i know about cloud computing, i know about web services, i know about android.... that i don't know is what kind of application to develop for android that use an Web Service that is hosted in cloud... Currently im thinking for "Cloud Contacts - Backup contacts in the cloud". But i think WSs are unnecessary in this case.

Comment: @GeorgeJ You want to back up your phone contacts in the web, so let's say the phone was factory reset and you lost all your contacts and you want to access the stored one in the cloud. You need NO-SQL DB (don't remember the AWS name for this service): each entry is OOP object `Person` with trivial attributes rather then traditional SQL entry - It's just better design because contact is more OOP thinking...

Comment: And then you  need exactly rest api as WS so mobile contact backend via this api, and this api get data from DB and return it to mobile. try use aws elastic beanstalk env inside it the no sql db and Apache tomcat to run ws which will be lets say jar file: you write java program which exposes api (just like regular java program), some annotations to make it ws export to jar upload to aws

Comment: Yea! but i can get data back to the phone using simple php script. I am just saying that cloud computing (virtual servers) and web services for that example are just a noise... The Q was not if it is possible, but if it is recommented! Anyway... i will asfk for help from my teacher to decide. Currently i have 2 ideas > 1) Cloud Contacts using cloud & ws OR 2) Cloud Gallery (Photos, Music, Videos) -OR- Just Cloud Photo Gallery...

-- PS: Cloud Photo Gallery seems good idea! anyway! finally i found (decided) something that the usage of cloud computing and web services is useful.Ty again for help